# Trying To Install Skype On Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: skype, dependencies

I have a machine on Ubuntu 12.04LTS I was looking to install skype on this system. I've tried all the possible solutions from getting the file from the official site to using Terminal. I seemed to be failing. Whenever I try to install Skype I always get this error , no matter where I install it from.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command and remove the broken package,

```
apt-mark showhold 
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

After doing so remove the package for skype and install it again.

Comment: I seemed to have fixed the problem by using sudo apt-get clean . Thanks for the support!

Comment: We are glad to know the issue has fixed. Wish you happy new year !

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

If problem persists, try

```
sudo dpkg--reconfigure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

See if that solves the issue.